# Is it possible to build a chart in email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, html

I want to build a chart dynamically in the email by using the data in data extension, is it doable? how can i go about it?

Comment: the tag says marketing cloud. This is possible in salesforce  sales cloud and service cloud using visualforce template not sure about marketing cloud though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Suppose you had a data extension called "Car_Models" with car model and make.

Create a field in your data extension called "Keyfield" and default it with a value of "X".  This will allow you to lookup that value and loop through the entire set of records. (max 2500)

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Model</td>
    <td>Make</td>
  </tr>
  %%[
  set @rows = LookupRows("Car_Models","Keyfield", "x")
  set @rowcount = RowCount(@rows)

  for @x = 1 to @rowcount do 
  set @row = row(@rows,@x)
  set @model = field(@row,"model")
  set @make = field(@row,"make")    
  ]%%
  <tr>
<td>%%=v(@model)=%% </td>
<td>%%=v(@make)=%% </td>
 </tr>
  %%[next @x]%% 
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: Hi K-grifn this will render a table, i want to render a chart at least a bar graph.

Comment: Hi @Sanjay  - There isn't a built in way to do this or a good way to use AMPscript.  You would have to build something custom.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the relatively new "Marketing Cloud Content Block SDK":

[Official info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/content-sdk.htm)

[Great introduction by Eliot Harper](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/salesforce-marketing-cloud-content-block-sdk-explained-eliot-harper/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base_recent_activity_details_shares%3BiNFNFJtiQ1W8FjnSAhVuKQ%3D%3D)